# add System.Security.Cryptography.Xml library to .net framework 4.6 project

Tags: cryptography, system.security

I try to add package via nuget but this error occurs;

> Could not install package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Xml 4.4.2'.
>   You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Ok message is clear but there is a code peace and I moved it to my project. How can I make it work ? it requires this library

```
public string SignXml(XmlDocument xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 uidCert)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Create a SignedXml object.
                    SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
```

Answer (score 2):

`SignedXml` is already available in .NET Framework, you just need to add a reference to System.Security.dll

The NuGet package is for .NET Core, but can be used by .NET Standard (2.0) libraries which run on .NET Core 2.0+ or .NET Framework 4.6.1+. (The .NET Framework implementation just forwards to System.Security.dll).

Alternatively, upgrade your minimum target to 4.6.1 or higher (4.6.1 is 2 and a half years old at this point... and at 4.6 you’re 5 versions out of date).